# How to hide all other elements when a sub-element of one is clicked

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I need to be able to hide elements that have been generated dynamically by `ng-repeat` by clicking in **other** elements that were also created by ng-repeat. Example HTML:

```
<div ng-repeat="thing in things" ng-show="!displayId || displayId == 'thing.id'">
    <button ng-click="displayId = 'thing.id'">Click me!</button>
</div>
```

The initial display works fine, since `displayId` is unspecified until a button is clicked, but what I expect to happen is `displayId` gets set to the `thing.id` of whatever button I click, and once it's set, all other divs get hidden. However, nothing happens.

Is there a way to accomplish this? I'm trying not to use any jquery and do this in a purely angular way.

Comment: Have you tried bubbling up?

Comment: Ooo, bubbling is actually next on my reading list. Is that where my solution lies? If so, I'm happy to run off and do some reading.

Comment: Wait are you trying to filter out a list of buttons to only show the button you clicked, because this could be a great use-case for a filter.

Comment: Yes, exactly. There's more in the <div> and more that the button does. This is just the part that isn't working.

Comment: Don't really understand what you want do. How can a click a button, which is not visible, because another one was clicked before. One help I can give is that `ng-repeat` creates a child scope, so use `$parent.displayId` instead

Comment: @robkub, the idea is to click an element and hide **other** elements. Your help may very well be what I was looking for, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So based on the extra detail you provided, you can use `filter` on your `ng-repeat`.

```
<div ng-repeat="thing in things | filter:{id: selectedThingId}">
    <button ng-click="setSelectedThing(thing.id)">Click me!</button>
</div>
```

And in your controller:

```
$scope.selectedThingId;
$scope.setSelectedThingId = function setSelectedThingIdFn(thingId) {
  $scope.selectedThingId = thingId;
}
```

### Here is an embedded Plunker Example:

```html
<iframe style="width: 100%; height: 600px" src="http://embed.plnkr.co/tpMSLcpEGkoWx4eGDcHo/preview" frameborder="0" allowfullscren="allowfullscren"></iframe>
```

Comment: This looks good. Give me three minutes to implement it, and if it works, I'll mark this as the answer.

Comment: So I'm going to mark this as the answer, because 1) it works, and 2) I think I can actually use this elsewhere, too.

Comment: Yeah hopefully this syntax makes sense in terms of filtering.